# convert or figure formula which is contained parentheses

Tags: c#, parentheses

i need to find a way to conert treated formula(just using digits,letters and parentheses)
for example, for this input: '`5(2(a)sz)`' the output should be :'`aaszaaszaaszaaszaasz`'
i tried in that way:

```
string AddChainDeleteBracks(int open, int close, string input)
    {
        string to="",from="";
        //get the local chain multipule the number in input[open-1]

        //the number of the times the chain should be multiplied
        for (int i = input[open - 1]; i > 0; i--)
        {
            //the content
            for (int m = open + 1; m < close; m++)
            {
                to = to + input[m];
            }
        }

        //get the chain i want to replace with "to"
        for (int j = open - 1; j <= close; j++)
        {
            from = from + input[j];
        }
        String output = input.Replace(from, to);
        return output;
    }
```

but it doesn't work. Do u have a better idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the opening parenthesis positions along with the number associated with that parenthesis in a stack (Last-in-First-out, e.g. [System.Collections.Generic.Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx)); then when you encounter the first (that is: next) closing parenthesis, pop the top of the stack: this will give you the beginning and ending position of the substring between the (so far most inner) parentheses you need to repeat.  Then replace this portion of the original string (including the repetion number) with the repeated string.  Continue until you reach the end of the string.

Things to be aware of:

- when you do the replacement, you will need to update your current position so it now points to the end of the repetiotion string in the new (modified) string
- depending whether 0 repetion is allowed, you might need to handle an empty repetition -- that is an empty string
- when you reach the end of the string, the stack should be empty (all opening parentheses were matched with a closing one)
- the stack might become empty in the middle of the string -- if you encounter a closing parentheses, the input string was malformed
- there might be a way to escape the opening/cloding parentheses, so they don't count as part of the repetition pattern -- this depends on your requirements

Comment: Which part(s) do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: i did it without stack and it doesn't work. in the same method.

Comment: The stack is crutial here: it allows you to "remmeber" all the open parentheses you encountered so far and go back to them in the order you need to match them to the closing parentheses.  Also "it doens't work" is not helpful.  You should provide 1) example input, 2) what you expect the outcome to be, 3) what you actually get.  Try debugging the behavior in a debugger, step-by-step and see what happens, how it is different from what you expect/want

Answer (score 0):

Since the syntax of your expression is recursive, I suggest a recursive approach.

First split the expression into single tokens.  I use `Regex` to do it and remove empty entries.

Example: `"5(2(a)sz)"` is split into `"5", "(", "2", "(", "a", ")", "sz", ")"`

Using an Enumerator enables you to get the tokens one by one. `tokens.MoveNext()` gets the next token. `tokens.Current` is the current token.

```
public string ConvertExpression(string expression)
{
    IEnumerator<string> tokens = Regex.Split(expression, @"\b")
                    .Where(s => s != "")
                    .GetEnumerator();
    if (tokens.MoveNext()) {
        return Parse(tokens);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Here the main job is done in a recursive way

```
private string Parse(IEnumerator<string> tokens)
{
    string s = "";
    while (tokens.Current != ")") {
        int n;
        if (tokens.Current == "(") {
            if (tokens.MoveNext()) {
                s += Parse(tokens);
                if (tokens.Current == ")") {
                    tokens.MoveNext();
                    return s;
                }
            }
        } else if (Int32.TryParse(tokens.Current, out n)) {
            if (tokens.MoveNext()) {
                string subExpr = Parse(tokens);
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    sb.Append(subExpr);
                }
                s += sb.ToString();
            }
        } else {
            s += tokens.Current;
            if (!tokens.MoveNext())
                return s;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: what did u do here? i don't understand!

Comment: Your expression is nested, i.e. inside parentheses might be other parentheses, and so on. Therefore the method `Parse` calls itself and returns the coneverted expression of the inner expression to the outer expression. This is called a recursion. You can see what happens by using the debugger. If you show the Call-Stack-Window you also see how the calls are nested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my second answer. My first answer was a quick shot. Here I tried to create a parser by doing the things one by one.

In order to convert an expression, you need to parse it. This means that you have to analyze its syntax. While analyzing its syntax you can produce an output as well.

## 1 The first thing to do, is to define the syntax of all the valid expressions.

Here I use EBNF to do it. EBNF is simple.

`{` and `}` enclose repetitions (possibly zero).
`[` and `]` encloses an optional part.
`|` separates alternatives.

See [Extended Backus–Naur Form (EBNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) on Wikpedia for more detailed information on EBNF. (The EBNF variant used here drops the concatenation operator ",").

Our syntax in EBNF

```
Expression = { Term }.
Term = [ Number ] Factor.
Factor = Text | "(" Expression ")" | Term.
```

Examples

```
    5(2(a)sz)  =>  aaszaaszaaszaaszaasz
    5(2a sz)   =>  aaszaaszaaszaaszaasz
    2 3(a 2b)c  =>  abbabbabbabbabbabbc
```

## 2 Lexical analysis

Before we analyze the syntax we have to split the whole expression into single lexical tokens (numbers, operators, etc.).
We use an `enum` to indicate the token type

```
private enum TokenType
{
    None,
    LPar,
    RPar,
    Number,
    Text
}
```

The following fields are used to hold the token information and the Boolean `_error` which tells whether an error occurred during parsing.

```
private IEnumerator<Match> _matches;
TokenType _tokenType;
string _text;
int _number;
bool _error;
```

The method `ConvertExpression` starts the conversion. It splits the expression into single tokens represented as `Regex.Matches`.
Those are used by the method `GetToken`, which in turn converts the `Regex.Matches` into more useful information. This information is stored in the fields described above.

```
public string ConvertExpression(string expression)
{
    _matches = Regex.Matches(expression, @"\d+|\(|\)|[a-zA-Z]+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .GetEnumerator();
    _error = false;
    return GetToken() ? Expression() : "";
}

private bool GetToken()
{
    _number = 0;
    _tokenType = TokenType.None;
    _text = null;
    if (_error || !_matches.MoveNext())
        return false;

    _text = _matches.Current.Value;
    switch (_text[0]) {
        case '(':
            _tokenType = TokenType.LPar;
            break;
        case ')':
            _tokenType = TokenType.RPar;
            break;
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            _tokenType = TokenType.Number;
            _number = Int32.Parse(_text);
            break;
        default:
            _tokenType = TokenType.Text;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

## 3 Syntactic and Semantic Analysis

Now we have everything we need to perform the actual parsing and expression conversion. Each of the methods below analyses one EBNF syntax production and returns the result of the conversion as string.
The conversion of EBNF into C# code is straight forward. A repetition in the syntax is converted to a C# loop statement.
An option is converted to an `if` statement and alternatives are converted to a `switch` statement.

```
// Expression = { Term }.
private string Expression()
{
    string s = "";
    do {
        s += Term();
    } while (_tokenType != TokenType.RPar && _tokenType != TokenType.None);
    return s;
}

// Term = [ Number ] Factor.
private string Term()
{
    int n;
    if (_tokenType == TokenType.Number) {
        n = _number;
        if (!GetToken()) {
            _error = true;
            return " Error: Factor expected.";
        }

        string factor = Factor();
        if (_error) {
            return factor;
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder(n * factor.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sb.Append(factor);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    return Factor();
}

// Factor = Text | "(" Expression ")" | Term.
private string Factor()
{
    switch (_tokenType) {
        case TokenType.None:
            _error = true;
            return " Error: Unexpected end of Expression.";
        case TokenType.LPar:
            if (GetToken()) {
                string s = Expression();
                if (_tokenType == TokenType.RPar) {
                    GetToken();
                    return s;
                } else {
                    _error = true;
                    return s + " Error ')' expected.";
                }
            } else {
                _error = true;
                return " Error: Unexpected end of Expression.";
            }
        case TokenType.RPar:
            _error = true;
            GetToken();
            return " Error: Unexpected ')'.";
        case TokenType.Text:
            string t = _text;
            GetToken();
            return t;
        default:
            return Term();
    }
}
```

Comment: My first answer did not explain much. I've tried to proceed more systematically here and hope that this useful to Noam650
 or someone else.